# Generate a dictionary from mySQL Table in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, dictionary, mysqli

I am working on a project for my php website that requires taking user input from a form and comparing it to values stored in a database table. I am new to php but the Objective-C part of me says I should use a dictionary. I have found many tutorials on arrays, nothing on dictionaries, and all of them break my code and displays nothing on the page. Should I use an array or a dictionary, and what am I doing wrong? The sample table is below.

```
+------------------------------+
|            codes             |
+----+--------------+----------+
| id | access_codes | code_used|
+----+--------------+----------+
|  0 |     FS1      |    NO    |
+----+--------------+----------+
|  1 |     FS2      |    NO    |
+----+--------------+----------+
```

index.php:

```
<?php
    require_once('../../config.php');
?><!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Redeem Code</title>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
        <!--
        <script>
            function SubmitForm() {
                //Javascript needed?
            }
        </script>
        -->
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="?checkCode" method="Post">
            <p>Access Code: </p><input type="text" name="lname"><br>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit">
        </form>
    </body>
<html>

<?php
    function checkCode() {
        $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT access_codes FROM codes");
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
            $access_code=$row['access_codes'];
            $code_array[] = $access_code;
        }
        echo $code_array;
        mysqli_close($con);
    }

?>
```

Edit:

```
<?php
    require_once('../../config.php');
        $con=mysqli_connect(DB_HOST,DB_USER,DB_PASSWORD,DB_NAME);
        if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
            echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
        }
        $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT access_codes FROM codes");
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
            $access_code=$row['access_codes'];
            if ( array_key_exists( $access_code, $code_array ) ) {
                $code_array[$access_code] ++;
            }
            else {
                $code_array[$access_code] = 1;
            }
        }
        foreach ($code_array as $access_code => $count) {
            echo sprintf("<tr> <td> %1$s </td><td> %2$d </td></tr>", $access_code, $count);
        }
        mysqli_close($con);

?>
```

Comment: In PHP, arrays *are* dictionaries - unless I'm misinterpreting your definition of 'dictionary'.

Answer (score 1):

```
echo $code_array;  // wrong
```

You cannot "write" a field. You can use `print_r` statement:

```
print_r($code_array);
```

Answer (score 0):

Like @Qix said, php arrays can be used as dictionaries.  When you use them as arrays, they're integer-indexed. But they can be indexed by keys as well.

For example, this code will count occurrences of `access_codes` values by creating an array (a dictionary) indexed by the values, containing a count in each value.

```
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
        $access_code=$row['access_codes'];
        if ( array_key_exists( $access_code, $code_array ) ) {
            $code_array[$access_code] ++;
        }
        else {
            $code_array[$access_code] = 1;
        }
     }
```

You can't just echo a complex data type, you have to iterate through it. You could do that like this with `foreach`.

```
 foreach ($code_array as $access_code => $count) {
     echo sprintf("<tr> <td> %1$s </td><td> %2$d </td></tr>", $access_code, $count);
 }
```

Sometimes when you're debugging PHP it's helpful to do View Source in your browser, so you can view what's going on.

Comment: I created edits as shown in the `Edit:` code section. However, nothing shows on the page. I removed the HTML to reduce clutter.

Comment: View Source... can be helpful for debugging.